# Load local zoomify tileset in OL3

Tags: openlayers-3, zoomify

I produced a zoomify tileset from some digitized map image and would now like to use OL3 to display that map on a Website. However, my script currently fails loading that map from a local file uri (later, in production, I will upload the tiles on some Web Server and reference the tiles using HTTP). Here is what I have so far:

```
  var url = 'file:///home/user/map_zoomfiy/';
  var imgWidth = 17244;
  var imgHeight = 9684;

  var imgCenter = [imgWidth / 2, - imgHeight / 2];

  var proj = new ol.proj.Projection({
    code: 'ZOOMIFY',
    units: 'pixels',
    extend: [0, 0, imgWidth, imgHeight]
  });

  var source = new ol.source.Zoomify({
    url: url,
    size: [imgWidth, imgHeight],
    crossOrigin: 'anonymous'
  });

  var map = new ol.Map({
    target: 'map',
    layers: [
      new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: source
      })
    ],
    view: new ol.View({
      projection: proj,
      center: imgCenter,
      zoom: 1
    })
  });

</script>
```

Any ideas why this fails? Thx.

Answer (score 0):

It's not right way e.g https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebGuide/API/File_System/Introduction#file

I don't see why you do not make a local server instead of fighting to access your file with local url.

Some times ago, I compiled [some recipes](https://thomasg77.github.io/2013/05/24/multi-languages-one-liner-web-servers.html) to do so.

Open your command line, go to your code root dir and follow recipes depending of your favorite programming language.

Answer (score 0):

If the tiles are in a subdirectory (e.g., `tiles_zoomify`) the following should work

```
var url = 'tiles_zoomify/';
var imgWidth = 17244;
var imgHeight = 9684;

var imgCenter = [imgWidth / 2, - imgHeight / 2];

var proj = new ol.proj.Projection({
  code: 'ZOOMIFY',
  units: 'pixels',
  extend: [0, 0, imgWidth, imgHeight]
});

var source = new ol.source.Zoomify({
  url: url,
  size: [imgWidth, imgHeight],
  crossOrigin: 'anonymous'
});

var map = new ol.Map({
  target: 'map',
  layers: [
    new ol.layer.Tile({
      source: source
    })
  ],
  view: new ol.View({
    projection: proj,
    center: imgCenter,
    zoom: 1
  })
});
```